# Html, table, img & css - how to get text to wrap correctly?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got the following code; however it's not given me the desired result - what I am after is as per the image below, what am I doing wrong?

```
<style>
table.control_grid tr {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
table.control_grid td {
    width: 120px;
    height: 48px;
}
table.control_grid a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
table.control_grid img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
</style>

<table class="control_grid">
    <tr>
        <td><img width="48" height="48" src="icon1.gif">My text & stuff, overflow??</td>
        <td><img width="48" height="48" src="icon1.gif">Icon1</td>
        <td><img width="48" height="48" src="icon1.gif">Icon2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Desired result:

[Desired result http://mpasqualone.com/wantedResult.gif](http://mpasqualone.com/wantedResult.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should float the images.

> float:left;

Comment: This + table-layout seems to be the most cleanest method, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

This triggers the ‘fixed table layout algorithm’, in which the horizontal layout only depends on the table’s width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells.

Apart from fixing your problem, this improves performance as well: a fixed table layout allows browsers to render the table faster than the automatic table layout, because the browser can begin to display the table once the first row has been received.

Comment: Not quite true: `table-layout: fixed;` makes column width be calculated taking into account only the first line, instead of all lines as usual. See http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/table-layout/ Needs to float images to make text wrap around them.

Answer (score 1):

one thing you've missed, close the img tag like this(and don't forget the alt attr :) )

```
<img width="48" height="48" src="icon1.gif" alt="" />
```

Above code is xhtml compliant

Comment: Whoops! Thanks, I've got alt tags and stuff in it as well - just trying to get a barebones positioning right. CSS is doing my head in!

Answer (score 0):

Use like this for your desired output :

```
<table class="control_grid">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><img width="48" height="48" src="icon1.gif" align="left">My text & stuff, overflow??</td>
        <td valign="top"><img width="48" height="48" src="icon1.gif">Icon1</td>
        <td valign="top"><img width="48" height="48" src="icon1.gif">Icon2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```